# multiprocessing initialising a function in a class

Tags: python, class, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to initialise a function in a class using multiprocessing, by calling it from a function, which is inside the same same class

```
    def Streaminit(self,_track):
        self.twitterStream = tweepy.Stream(self.auth, Twitterapi.Listener())
        self.twitterStream.filter(track=_track)

    def Stream(self,track=""):
        self.streamobj = multiprocessing.Process(target = self.Streaminit(),args=(track,))
```

but when I call stream it raises an error

`TypeError: Streaminit() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

What am I doing wrong in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.streamobj = multiprocessing.Process(target = self.Streaminit(),args=(track,))
```

You're calling the `Streaminit` function here with no arguments, and it takes one argument (plus `self`). So naturally it'll cause an error.

What it looks like you wanted to do was pass the function itself to `multiprocessing.Process`:

```
self.streamobj = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.Streaminit, args=(track,))
```